# ASP.NET Web API Core: complex data model binder to trim strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Can someone shed some light of how to implement model binder for complex types?
I'd like all string properties to be trimmed. I tried the following but 
"SetProperty" method is never called.

```
public class TrimmingModelBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder  
{
    public TrimmingModelBinder(IDictionary propertyBinders) : base(propertyBinders)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string modelName, ModelMetadata propertyMetadata, ModelBindingResult result)
    {
        if(result.Model is string)
        {
            string resultStr = (result.Model as string).Trim();
            result = ModelBindingResult.Success(resultStr);
        }

        base.SetProperty(bindingContext, modelName, propertyMetadata, result);
    }
}

public class TrimmingModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
        {
            var propertyBinders = context.Metadata.Properties.ToDictionary(p => p, context.CreateBinder);
            return new TrimmingModelBinder(propertyBinders);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495432/asp-net-core-mvc-mixed-route-frombody-model-binding-validation

Answer (score 4):

Here's how we do it.

A simple helper extension method:

```
static class NormalizeString
{
    public static string TrimAndNullIfWhiteSpace(this string text) =>
       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
       ? null
       : text.Trim();
}
```

Create a custom ModelBinder for strings:

```
public class StringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        if (modelName == NullOrWhiteSpace)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        if(valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(
            valueProviderResult.FirstValue.TrimAndNullIfWhiteSpace());

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create a custom ModelBinderProvider that references the custom ModelBinder:

```
public class ModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(StringModelBinder));

        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally, register the customer ModelBinderProvider in Startup's ConfigureServices:

```
    services
        .AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ModelBinderProvider());
        })
```

Comment: I have implemented this and it seems to have the desired result so far, so thanks, but in your `ModelBinderProvider` class why not just `return new StringModelBinder()` instead of wrapping it in the `BinderTypeModelBinder` class; is there any advantage of doing so?

Comment: @ChristopherKing It's been a few years, so I'm sorry I can't remember. What happens when you try without `BinderTypeModelBinder`?