# Bind multiple parameters from route and body to a model in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I provide an ID in the route (".../api/mobile/registers/192" - 192 is ID) and the rest of params in the body of a PUT-request. How to bing them to a model with all the parameters? The problem is that the ID does not map, it is always 0:

```
[HttpPut("registers/{id}")]
public async Task ModifyPaymentRegister(PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm model)
{
    var result = await financeService.ModifyPaymentRegisterAsync(model, CurrentUserId.Value);
    ...
}
```

```
    [BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)]
    public class PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Идентификатор реестра
        /// </summary>
        [FromRoute]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Описание реестра
        /// </summary>
        [FromBody]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Тип модификации реестра
        /// </summary>
        [FromBody]
        public PaymentModifyType ModifyType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Check FromBody like :  
public string MyMethod([FromBody] JObject data){}

Comment: Anyway, the body parameters are mapped, but the ID is not.

Comment: you should change the route parameter from `id` to `Id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot pass an `object` from route to an action method.
for passing data from route to method, ***the route parameter name must be exactly as same as the method parameter***. If you wanna pass multiple parameters you should act like below:

```
[HttpGet("api/v1/Users/{name}/{surname}")]
public string GetUser(string name,string surname)
{
    return "Hello " + name + " " + surname;
}
```

this code work with the below URLs:

- `localhost:3001/api/v1/Users/Hamed/Moghadasi`
- `localhost:3001/api/v1/Users?name=Hamed&surname=Moghadasi`

**BUT**, I would like to say that the right way to send complex data objects to an API is using request `body`. so you can simply put your data in the request body and easily get it in the method by using `[FromBody]`, your code should be like below:

```
[HttpPut("registers")]
public async Task ModifyPaymentRegister([FromBody]PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm model)
```

for going deeper you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) link.
good luck.

Answer (score 2):

well what you are trying to achieve, by using the same model, seems to be impossible:

look at msft docs:
[image: Msft Docs]

the answers above all gave you an alternative solution.
This is the solution you were really looking for though:

[ASP.NET Core MVC Mixed Route/FromBody Model Binding & Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495432/asp-net-core-mvc-mixed-route-frombody-model-binding-validation/45496917)

Posting this so that if anyone hops onto this issue finds the real answer/implementation to achieve this. not a workaround

Comment: I also learned there is a library which offers [FromHybrid] attribute which enables this - nuget is HybridModelBinding

Comment: "The answers above" does not make sense on StackOverflow. E.g., your answer is the top-most answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the **id as a parameter** too.

public async Task ModifyPaymentRegister(**int id,** PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm model)

By default, aspnet hides the use of notations, so the second parameter is like [FromBody] PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm model)

Try this:

```
[HttpPut("registers/{id}")]
public async Task ModifyPaymentRegister(int id, PaymentRegisterModifyRequestVm model)
{
    var result = await financeService.ModifyPaymentRegisterAsync(model, CurrentUserId.Value);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this option works well, thanks. I wanted to find a way to use a sole model.