# Not able to receive values from Route and Body in a POST call

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

On an Asp.Net Core 5.0 project I have the `ApiController` route and Model:

```
[HttpPost("users/{userId:int}/confirm-email")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(Model model) { }

public class Model { 
  [FromRoute] public Int32? UserId { get; set; }
  [FromQuery] public String Token { get; set; } 
}
```

**Result:** I got what I expected ...

```
UserId = 10
Token = "ABC"
```

I tried receive the token in the Body and not in the query parameter:

```
public class Model { 
  [FromRoute] public Int32? UserId { get; set; }
  [FromBody] public String Token { get; set; } 
}
```

In this case I got the error:

```
"errors": {
  "$": [
    "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
  ]
}
```

I used Insomnia.Rest to call the API and the body is:

```
{
  "token": "ABC"
}
```

Then I tried to add `[FromBody]` to Controller action:

```
[HttpPost("users/{userId:int}/confirm-email")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail([FromBody]Model model) { }

public class Model { 
  [FromRoute] public Int32? UserId { get; set; }
  [FromBody] public String Token { get; set; } 
}
```

**Result:** I got the token from body but now userId is null.

```
UserId = null
Token = "ABC"
```

I have been trying a few variations but I can't figure out what is happening.

I also tried to call the API from Angular and the result is the same.

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the url are you using  for route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind multiple parameters from route and body to a model in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027159/bind-multiple-parameters-from-route-and-body-to-a-model-in-asp-net-core) N.B. the answer by user fattikus that basically says you can't do what you're trying to do, exactly. However, you should be able to access `userId` within the the body of `ConfirmEmail()` by making it a local variable there, rather than making it part of the model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs from the following sources in an HTTP request:

- Form fields
- The request body (For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute.)
- Route data
- Query string parameters
- Uploaded files

For each target parameter or property, the sources are scanned in the order indicated in the preceding list.

You can refer the following screenshot:

[image]

We can see that, the `[FromRoute]` and the `[FromForm]` attribute which apply to the property is not working. It uses the default inference rules to bind model.

Then, when the `[FromBody]` attribute is applied to a complex type parameter (add the `[FromBody]` attribute to Controller action), any binding source attributes applied to its properties are ignored. So, the `UserId` is null. More detail information, see [`[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#frombody-attribute-1) and [Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference).

So, in this scenario, to access the value from route and request body, the easiest way is adding a parameter in the `ConfirmEmail` method, code as below:

```
    [HttpPost("users/{userId:int}/confirm-email")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(Model model, [FromRoute]int userid)
    {
        //set the userid
        model.userId = userid;

        return Ok("success");
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

Besides, you can also try to create a Custom model binder to bind the model.

Here are some relate articles, you can refer them:

[Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Custom Model Binding In ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)